# mysql slower query when using limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( 
id   BIGINT(11) autoincrement, 
mark TINYINT(1))
INDEX(id,mark);
```

I inserted 50000000 rows into this table.

I use the sql query:

```
SELECT   * FROM t 
WHERE    t.id > last_id AND mark =1 
ORDER BY id
LIMIT    10000;
```

`last_id` is max(id) of the last query result.

At first few queries takes 0.3 seconds. but when the `last_id` > 1000000 , it takes 5.2 seconds.

the index work well,but go slower when last_id is bigger
Where is the problem?

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` on your query to better understand how it is being executed.

Comment: plz post your last_id query

Comment: Your index cannot be used for ordering, so you have filesort. The index `(mark, id)` needed.

Comment: If possible create a `non-cluster index` where clause filed.

Answer (score 0):

Try mysql range wise partitioning.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the query like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t 
WHERE t.id > last_id AND mark = 1 
ORDER BY mark, id
LIMIT 10000;
```

The addition of `mark` to the `ORDER BY` may seem useless, because `mark` is filtered to only be `1`.  However, the conditions exactly match the index, so you might get a better execution plan -- you want to avoid the filesort for sorting the data.